# Aldryn NewsBlog - one particular blog instance multiple times

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I am using [aldryn-newsblog](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-newsblog), and would like to include the top three first blog posts to my home/index page, along with other elements like a gallery slider and a newsletter sign up.

How can I render the first three blog post from the aldryn news-blog into the tpl_home.html template used on my home/index page?

This is the default **tpl_home.html** template:

```
{% extends "fullwidth.html" %}

{% block body_class %}tpl-home{% endblock %}
```

This is the default **article_list.html**:

```
{% extends "aldryn_newsblog/two_column.html" %}
{% load i18n cms_tags %}

{% block newsblog_content %}
    {% render_placeholder view.config.list_view_placeholder language placeholder_language %}
    <div class="aldryn-newsblog-list">
        {% for article in article_list %}
            {% include "aldryn_newsblog/includes/article.html" %}
        {% empty %}
            <p class="well">{% trans "No items available" %}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block newsblog_footer %}
    <div class="aldryn-newsblog-pagination">
        {% include "aldryn_newsblog/includes/pagination.html" %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I have basically tried to copy the content of the **article_list.html** file to the **tpl_home.html**, as well as changing the **aldryn_blog/two_column.html**

from `{% extends "aldryn_newsblog/base.html" %}` 
to `{% extends "base.html" %}`

But all I get is the *"No items available"* error, from the **article_list.html**.

I have also tried to add the blog instance to the home page using the django-CMS GUI, but keep getting this error *"An application instance using this configuration already exists.".*

Is there a way to include one particular blog instance multiple times on different sites?

Answer (score 1):

This is a little old at this point, but for anybody who stumbles across it:
*You don't need to touch* `{% extends <anything> %}` -- anytime you use the extends tag, it's going to pull in the entire page that follows it, which will either result in an error, an extremely funky page, or just generally undesired results. Depending on your setup, there are two methods to accomplish what you're trying to do:

**1. Using the Aldryn setup.**

As far as articles_list.html goes, that's simply one piece of your blog page's puzzle: The one that lists the articles. What you're looking for can be done entirely through the front-end editing, with the "Latest Articles" plugin. Below is the structure laid out by default for my `tpl_home.html`:

[This doesn't need to go into the "Header" section -- you can arrange the order of appearance however you like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZbTI.png)

It's a perfect plugin for your needs, as you can specify the number of selected articles to be shown once you've clicked on the plugin, as well as which blog (if you have more than one) you'd like them to come from:

[You should see this when you click on the plugin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8vw6.png)

As for the gallery slider: I've never used it, but I do have the Aldryn Gallery package installed, and it has the option displayed in the link below, so I believe that's the route you'd take to get that on your page. It can be installed through the "Manage Addons" page on your site's dashboard.

For a newsletter, Aldryn Mailchimp can also be installed via the "Manage Addons" page, but you'll first need to sign up for a free Mailchimp account on their site (linked to in the package details) to get an API key (this must be entered on the package's installation page before the installation will initiate). I've never personally used Mailchimp, but most newsletter services require you to give them $$$. Mailchimp kinda rocks, because it offers a free usage level that should be quite capable of handling your site's needs (12,000 emails a month are allowed). It also offers a ton of features for managing your campaigns/formats/other stuff (I haven't really looked into it). It's email submission form should be available as a plugin, just like "Recent Articles" and "Gallery," once installed.

Now onto...

**2. Not Using Aldryn.**

However you're using Aldryn-NewsBlog, the normal plugins should still be available, and it can be downloaded on github. How to use them, exactly, depends on your admin setup -- but you should still be able to use the "Latest Articles" plugin, with the same methods, if you have the package properly installed.

Same for your gallery slider: Download and install Aldryn-Gallery from GitHub, and you should be good to go with the slider option.

With Mailchimp, you can just go to their site, and they'll explain how to integrate their service into virtually anything from there. I don't have enough repo points to post more than two links, but evidently iframes in snippits don't count as links (so take *that*, stackexchange rules!) Run the snippit for a Mailchimp newsletter install video:

```html
<iframe src="//fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/5ou4sscmze" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" class="wistia_embed" name="wistia_embed" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen"
oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" width="600" height="400"></iframe>
```